# Does VS2010 pre-calculate preprocessor defined by #define?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, c-preprocessor

For Visual Studio 2010, if I define

```
#define PI 4.0f*atan(1.0f)
```

when `PI` is used somewhere later in the code, does the value needs to be calculate again or simply 3.1415926... being plugged in? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Because I heard someone says the compiler might optimize to replace it with 3.1415926.., depending on the compiler.

Comment: Macros are simple text substitutions, the compiler sees the expression more than once.  The optimizer in Visual Studio knows how to calculate the value at compile-time.  Not 100% sure about VS2010, it is getting old.

Comment: Floats are often calculated at runtime if you don't ask you compiler anything because of rounding and precision.

Comment: What if you had defined `atan()` yourself? The preprocessor cannot blindly assume which `atan` you meant. For all it knows, yours returns a complex number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `#define` will do a direct text replacement.  Because of that everywhere you have `PI` it will get replaced with `4.0f*atan(1.0f)`.  I would suspect the compiler would optimize this away during code generation but the only real way to know is to compile it and check the assembly.

I found this [little online tool](http://assembly.ynh.io/) that will take c++ code and generate the assembly output.  If you turn on optimizations you will see that the code generated to display `PI` is gone and it is now just a constant that gets referenced.

Answer (score 3):

`#define` is a "copy-paste" type of thing.  If your code says `std::cout << PI;` then the compiler pretends you typed `std::cout << 4.0f*atan(1.0f);`.

The values of defines are *not* calculated until they're used, and they're theoretically recalculated every time they're used.  However, most modern compilers will see `std::cout << 4.0f*atan(1.0f);` and do that calculation at compile time and will emit assembly for `std::cout << 3.14159265f;`, so the code is just as fast as if it were precalculated.

Unrelated, `#include` is *also* a copy-paste kind of thing, which is why we need include guards.

Answer (score 0):

When the preprocessor runs it will replace every instance of `PI` with `4.0*atan(1.0f)`.